# Failed a First Posts audit but I don't know why was my action wrong?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just fail [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4761319) First Post review. I think it answers the question.

Although it could get some help with some elaboration and reference etc but not worthy of deletion or vote.

But my assessment of it is apparently incorrect.

Where did I go wrong in my assessment?

Comment: The reason is even in the comment there...

Comment: @deviantfan That post most certainly *is* an answer to the question.  It would appear that the reviewers read the first sentence fragment and stopped reading, which is unfortunate.  A post that says, "I have the same problem, has anyone else found an answer" is NAA.  A post that says, "I had the same problem, you can solved it by doing [...]" is *an answer to the question*.

Answer (score 7):

That answer needed a little bit of editing love to improve its presentation, and I can't comment in the slightest on its technical accuracy, but it is clearly an attempted answer to the question.  The given reason for its deletion clearly does not apply, and it should be undeleted.

In this particular case, you acted appropriately, and the audit was what was wrong.  The post wasn't exactly great, but it certainly didn't merit deletion.

Comment: So, will it be undeleted? And Mr Fingers redeemed?

Comment: @I voted to undelete it.  Whether or not it collects enough undelete votes from others, I couldn't say.

Comment: I wonder if we need to alter the criteria for selecting audits, now that "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags are being fed into the review queues. If even a couple of people vote "looks good" on a review item, like happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4739915 maybe we shouldn't count those as strong audit cases. When moderators handled those, we were told to be strict about them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently but reviewers probably won't know that.

Comment: @BradLarson I posted a [new meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254082/audits-should-not-be-selected-from-posts-community-deleted-through-review) to discuss possible changes to the audit selection criteria.