# Erroneous audits are being selected from posts community deleted through Review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Currently, audits representing examples of posts that should be deleted can be selected from posts that were deleted through the review queue.  [This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254058/1159478) is one example of an audit of a post in which the reviewers took the improper action, and of course these audits can cause major problems for the system.

[This is the audit in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254058/1159478).

[This is the review that it was based on.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4739915)

This post wasn't deleted by a moderator.  It wasn't even deleted by 3 10k users.  Heck, it wasn't even a unanimous decision by the users who recommended deletion.

Clearly *some* tweaking of the audit selection criteria needs to be done here.

---

The first, and most obvious, change that comes to mind would be immediately excluding any reviews in which the decision to delete was not unanimous.  However I'm not sure if even that would be sufficient to ensure that any erroneous reviews aren't turned into audits.

Moderators are primarily brought in to evaluate Not an Answer and Very Low Quality posts when there isn't a clear consensus among the community, which means that those posts are almost certainly not well suited for audits.  Even if the audit correctly singles out a bad post, if it's not *obvious* why it's bad to the reviewers, it won't make a good audit.

Another option to consider would be posts that contain at least some 10k+ delete votes, rather than deletion *recommendations*.

Comment: `...excluding any reviews in which the decision to delete was not unanimous` -- It won't guarantee zero false positives, but it would certainly improve the accuracy.  For those hapless folks that summarily rubber-stamp such reviews, we have a stack of review suspensions we can hand out.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah.  That change is the no-brainer addition that clearly helps, and shouldn't be hard to implement.  I don't know if that will be *sufficient* though.  No other particularly great ideas come to mind.

Comment: One silver lining I can draw from the current audit system, which I think is worth keeping, is that hadn't it been for this audit that answer wouldn't have been undeleted and would have remained in the dungeon of deleted posts. And such improper reviews wouldn't have been brought to the limelight.